# Contact creation through Graph API producing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: php, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I've been using the Graph API for contact creation and synchronization between a master account and all of our organization's Office 365 accounts. This has been working well up until the past month or so.

My synchronization process involves querying a specific folder of the master account for contacts, caching them, and then running through the list of target users, creating contacts where necessary. Getting lists of contacts, creating contact folders, and deleting contacts all still works as expected. Creating a contact returns "ErrorInternalServerError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I have been using the client_credentials flow and checked that my app has the appropriate credentials in the Azure AD admin panel. Below is the JSON object that I'm POSTing for contact creation. This is happening regardless of contact, or target user.

```
{
"categories": [],
"birthday": null,
"fileAs": "GPS 00 Bob, Todd",
"displayName": "GPS 00 Bob, Todd",
"givenName": "Todd",
"initials": "T.G.0.B.",
"middleName": "",
"nickName": null,
"surname": "GPS 00 Bob",
"title": "",
"yomiGivenName": null,
"yomiSurname": null,
"yomiCompanyName": null,
"generation": "",
"emailAddresses": [
    {
        "name": "Email",
        "address": "todd.bob@contactsyncing.com"
    }
],
"imAddresses": [
    ""
],
"jobTitle": "Chief Financial Officer",
"companyName": "",
"department": "",
"officeLocation": null,
"profession": null,
"businessHomePage": null,
"assistantName": null,
"manager": null,
"homePhones": [
    ""
],
"mobilePhone": "",
"businessPhones": [
    ""
],
"homeAddress": {
    "street": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "countryOrRegion": "",
    "postalCode": ""
},
"businessAddress": {
    "street": "701 East Lumbar Ave",
    "city": "Minot",
    "state": "ND",
    "countryOrRegion": "United States of America",
    "postalCode": "68745"
},
"otherAddress": {},
"spouseName": null,
"personalNotes": null,
"children": []
}
```

*edit*
Additional information: I am posting to a specific contact folder with its ID. Here is an example of the URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/91bbdb7b-3b41-474c-93c9-99b1da960c18/contactFolders/AAMkADFlNzQ5NGQ5LTEwNjYtNGFiZS04NDlhLTViOGE0YzMzZjI3OQAuAAAAAAA9YtgrncHYSKObisZl7JkCAQChpNwDV4FXRaJC6UF1HyyuAAAAAAFFAAA=/contacts

Is that contactFolder ID properly formed?
*/edit*

The script is written in PHP and I'm simply cURLing these requests. Any thoughts are suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if any other information would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After filtering down contact fields to a bare minimum and then re-adding them one by one, I've found that the birthday field was at fault. It seems that the Graph API no longer accepts a **null** value for this. Removing the field completely if a birthday is not specified seems to have resolved the issue.

I consider this resolved. Perhaps the Graph API documentation should be updated to reflect this fact? Additionally, it would seem prudent to improve the API's response to this error. "InternalServerError" does not adequately describe the cause.

Thanks!